# With Dexie, how to update multiple objects with a non-primary index?

Tags: updates, indexeddb, bulkupdate, dexie

I want to do something like, `myTable.update({ location: 'Paris'}, { location: '' }` and have all the objects in `myTable` that have a `location` of 'Paris' get changed to have `location` set to empty string.

`location` is not a primary key, so there may be any number of objects in `myTable` that have `location` = 'Paris' before executing the command, but there should be none with `location` = 'Paris' after executing the command.

I come from a SQL background, so this seems like a very simple, basic function for a database.  But the [Dexie docs for Table.update()](https://dexie.org/docs/Table/Table.update()) indicate that it only supports using a primary key, and consequently can only update at most one object.  Surely, there's some way to do this other than looping to make multiple calls to update the database?  Some command I haven't seen?  Or am I failing to understand something about NoSql databases that I should know?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
myTable.where({location: 'Paris'}).modify({location: ''})
```

https://dexie.org/docs/Collection/Collection.modify()

Comment: I didn't realize `modify` would write to the db - I thought Collections were in memory only.  Thanks!